# No route matches when trying to edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

Here's the scoop: I've created a test app that allows users to create ideas and then add "bubbles" to these ideas. Currently, a bubble is just text. I've successfully linked bubbles to ideas. Furthermore, when a user goes to view an idea it lists all of the bubbles attached to that idea. The user can even delete the bubble for a given idea.

My problem lies in editing bubbles. When a user views an idea, he sees the idea's content as well as any bubbles for that idea. As a result, I've set all my bubble controls (editing and deleting) inside the ideas "show" view. My code for editing a bubble for an idea is `<%= link_to 'Edit Bubble', edit_idea_bubble_path %>`. I ran `rake routes` to find the correct path for editing bubbles and that is what was listed.

Here's my error: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"bubbles"}`

In my bubbles controller I have:

```
def edit
@idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
   @bubble = @idea.bubbles.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
  @bubble = @idea.bubbles.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @bubble.update_attributes(params[:bubble])
    format.html { redirect_to(@bubble, 
                  :notice => 'Bubble was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "Edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @bubble.errors,
                  :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

To go a step further, I have the following in my `routes.rb` file

```
resources :ideas do
  resources :bubbles
end
```

So far everything seems to function except when I try to edit a bubble.

I'd love some guidance.

Thanks!

Here's my `show.html.erb` file for Ideas:

```
<h2>Bubbles</h2>
<% @idea.bubbles.each do |bubble| %>
<p>
<b>Bubble:</b>   
<%= bubble.description %>
</p>    
<p> 
<%= link_to 'Edit Bubble', edit_idea_bubble_path (@idea) %> 
</p>    
<tb />  
<p>     
<%= link_to 'Delete Bubble', [bubble.idea, bubble],               
    :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this bubble?',               
    :method => :delete %>   
</p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a bubble:</h2>
<%= form_for([@idea, @idea.bubbles.build]) do |f| %>  
    <div class="field">    
    <%= f.label :description %><br />    
    <%= f.text_area :description %>  
    </div>  

    <div class="actions">    
    <%= f.submit %>  </div><% end %>
```

Following `edit_idea_bubble_path (@idea)`, here is the `edit.html.erb` file for Bubbles:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back to Ideas', ideas_path %>
```

And finally, my `_form.html.erb` file for Bubbles: this is where the problem lies, I believe

```
<% form_for([@idea, @idea.bubbles.build]) do |f| %>  
  <%= f.error_messages %>

<div class="field">    
    <%= f.label :description %><br />    
    <%= f.text_area :description %>  
</div>  

<div class="actions">    
    <%= f.submit %>  
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the idea and the bubble objects:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Bubble', edit_idea_bubble_path(@idea,@bubble) %>
```

**Update:**

Edit the _form.html.erb file

```
<% form_for([@idea, @bubble]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work but now when I click on "Edit Bubble" I get the following error `Couldn't find Bubble with ID=5 [WHERE ("bubbles".idea_id = 5)]`. Using `@idea` as the object in `edit_idea_bubble_path` returns the idea_id (which is 5), and doesn't link correctly to editing the bubble (I can't seem to link the edit to hit the bubble_id). Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, putting `@idea,@bubble` inside `edit_idea_bubble_path` returned another error, so I tried putting just `@idea`. `@bubble` also didn't work.

Comment: It did but it brought me to another problem. Now when I click to edit a bubble, it brings me to the form for creating a new one. When I call `edit_idea_bubble_path(@idea)` it doesn't use the bubbles id.

Comment: Please update the question above with the form tag you are using to edit the bubble.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still didn't work. When you click to edit a bubble it just brings up the form for creating a bubble. The edit link must not be catching the bubble id.

Answer (score 1):

First build the route in your show.html.erb file

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Bubble', edit_idea_bubble_path(@idea, bubble) %>
```

Then, your controller should have 2 objects for both @idea and @bubble

when action is new

```
@idea = Idea.find_by_id(:params[:idea_id])
@bubble = @idea.bubbles.build
```

when action is edit

```
@idea = Idea.find_by_id(:params[:idea_id])
@bubble = @idea.bubbles.find_by_id(:params[:bubble_id])
```

In your _form.html.erb

```
<% form_for([@idea, @bubble]) do |f| %>
```